# Error using UDCX files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections, sharepoint-library

I'm using InfoPath Form Libraries, the infopath files uses UDCX files to get the data.  InfoPath files and UDCX are in the same site collection and in same server "Server A". Now when I try to access the InfoPath files from "Server A", the InfoPath files works perfectly. But when an user tries to access from his machine, he gets the following errors,

1. The UDC file cannot be opened. The operation timed out.
2. InfoPath either cannot connect to the data source or the service has timed out.
3. The data connection file could not be accessed.
4. The form cannot run the specified query.

Note:

A. User has access to the Data Connection Library.

B. In Central Administration –> General Application Settings –> InfoPath Forms Services –> Configure InfoPath Forms Services: I have enabled "Cross Domain Access for User Form Templates".

C. In Central Administration –> General Application Settings –> InfoPath Forms Services –> Configure InfoPath Forms Services: I have Increased the "Data Connection Timeouts".

D. All the UDC files are approved and Checked in.

I'm using SharePoint 2010, InfoPath 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Karthik,

UDCX files have issues with them and its really hard to maintain them as connections, I had a bad experience using them!

Instead I would suggest to use a separate Web Service (WCF/ASMX) and use that in InfoPath.. This will give you more flexibility and you don't have to worry at all about permissions.. You just need to manage SharePoint permissions (gives you ability to use [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx))..

I have done a very large project using InfoPath forms with a separate library and all works well, never had a problem. Its an alternative rather answer to your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Its a migrated site, so I cant do any changes in the InfoPath files. Moreover I cant find the code behind file for the InfoPath forms.

Answer (score 1):

kindly run Hotfix for these problem

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980213

Regards
Manish

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will install the update and let you know :)